# Create shortcut file for metadata in local file-system using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I am working on sync app. At user login, instead of downloading data we are creating a shortcut for each file.

When the user clicks on that link we want to download the content of the file without redirecting the browser.

So when a user clicks on a shortcut file, it downloads the data without redirecting the browser.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Seems like a reasonable project.  Have you started working on it yet?

Comment: yes iam started .....................!

Comment: what is your question? the download via shortcut is likely a built-in feature of the operating system. do you need help creating those shortcuts? or shortcut = URL? App for which platform? or browser on windows? any existing code to start from?